# Mongoid inheritance without changing collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, mongoid, reverse

I have been using rails and mongoid and have the following models (as an example):

```
class SocialMedia
end

class Facebook < SocialMedia
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :fans
end

class Instagram < SocialMedia
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :fans
end
```

I wanted to move both "fans" fields from Facebook and Instagram to SocialMedia class (inherited) WITHOUT changing collections. If I do something like:

```
class SocialMedia
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :fans
end
```

I end up with a new collection called social_media with _type: being either facebook or instagram. Since this database is already quite huge, it is not an option to update that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using concerns. Create a concern like this

```
module Sociable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    field :fans
  end
end
```

And then include this module in both your models.

Answer (score 0):

> The collection for the model's documents can be changed at the class level if you would like them persisted elsewhere. 
>   - http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/documents.html

```
class SocialMedia
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :fans
end

class Facebook < SocialMedia
  store_in collection: "facebook"
end

class Instagram < SocialMedia
  store_in collection: "instagram"
end
```

Or

```
class SocialMedia
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :fans
  store_in collection: model_name.plural
end
```

Comment: This does not work in Mongoid v4 and up. store_in must be defined in class that includes Mongoid::Document.

Comment: They said in 2014 that you are not supposed to call store_in the derived classes. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-3538